# What are the proper tools, in 2021, to configure network in Debian?

Tags: debian, networking

Every time I have to configure the network (such as setting bridges, configuring bonding, etc.), I'm lost.

There are plenty of resources explaining how to do things through the changes in `/etc/network/interfaces`. Others claim that one should use the `ifconfig`, `brctl` and other similar commands instead of changing the files manually. Then there are others which claim that `ifconfig` is the thing of the past, and that one should use the `ip` command; but when I search for how to do such or such thing with `ip`, I'm usually back to the old commands or `/etc/network/interfaces`. And then there are those who tell that Network Manager should be used, but I never understood what it brings, nor how it is configured, and end up just disabling it everywhere.

Could someone explain what happened, historically, in Debian and Debian-derived distributions in terms of network management, what is deprecated, and what should be used to configure the network on a fresh new system in 2021?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.0.2.7/24
    gateway 192.0.2.254
```

https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration